# вывод значения ассоцитативного массива в heredoc

Tags: php

Добрый вечер.

```
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo <<<_END
<pre>
Author $row['author']
Title $row['title']
Category $row['category']
Year $row['year']
ISBN $row['isbn']
</pre>
_END;
```

Так, php не дает сделать. Почему-то не хочет пихать ассоциативный массив между _END-ами. Если заменить всё это на нумерованные массивы, то есть,

```
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
echo <<<_END
<pre>
Author $row[0]
Title $row[1]
Category $row[2]
Year $row[3]
ISBN $row[4]
</pre>
_END;
```

То всё работает прекрасно. Но хотелось бы работать с ассоциативными массивами, а не нумерованными. Приходится делать так:

```
$row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo 'Author: '.$row['author'].'<br>';
    echo 'Title: '.$row['title'].'<br>';
    echo 'Category: '.$row['category'].'<br>';
    echo 'Year: '.$row['year'].'<br>';
    echo 'ISBN: '.$row['isbn'].'<br>---------------------------------------------<br>';
    echo<<<_END
```

Так, вот, собственно, вопрос, может, кто-то знает, почему ассоциативный массив нельзя поместить между _END-ами, а нумерованный можно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо однозначно выделять конструкции переменных в строке.
Вот так:

```
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo <<<_END
<pre>
Author ${row['author']}
Title ${row['title']}
Category ${row['category']}
Year ${row['year']}
ISBN ${row['isbn']}
</pre>
_END;
```

[Подробнее в оф. документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)